# One Observer not being created, but another identical one is

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

Using `rxjs` with Angular 2 RC.1 and I'm creating a few `Observer's`. I have the following in a service:

```
taxRates$:  Observable<TaxRate[]>;
taxTables$: Observable<TaxTable[]>;
private _taxRatesObserver:  Observer<TaxRate[]>;
private _taxTablesObserver: Observer<TaxTable[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    this.taxRates$ = new Observable<TaxRate[]>(observer =>
        this._taxRatesObserver = observer
    ).share();

    this.taxTables$ = new Observable<TaxTable[]>(observer =>
        this._taxTablesObserver = observer
    ).share();
    // more stuff here
}
```

The `_taxRatesObserver` is created correctly, but `_taxTablesObserver` is not. When I inspect the dev tools, I see this:

`_taxRatesObserver:Subscriber
http:HttpService
taxRates$:RefCountObservable
taxTables$:RefCountObservable`

I'd expect to also see `_taxTablesObserver:Subscriber` but if I log it via the console, it always shows as `undefined`. `TaxTable`, if it matters, looks like this:

`export class TaxTable {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public description: string) {}
}`

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> subscribe the function that is  called when the Observable is initially subscribed to.

_taxRatesObserver and _taxTablesObserver are initialized after subscription to taxRates$ and taxTables$ correspondingly.

Most probably taxTables$ does not have subscribers.

Comment: I commented out the subscribers from `_taxRatesObserver` and it still shows as an object vs undefined.

Comment: try to add debugger statement or console.trace() to find caller

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're suggesting, @kemsky.

Comment: ok, instead, try to subscribe to taxTables$ immediately after initialization and check if value is assigned.

Comment: It is not, I've already done this. Even still, I'm not doing that with `taxRates$` and it works just fine.

Comment: The problem ended up being I wasn't referencing taxTables in my view yet. I'm unsure as to why that matters, but after doing that, things worked. I'll post an answer to that effect later.